# Rails + Passenger + Apache + Alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, alias, virtualhost

I have a problem with Rails + Passenger + Apache + Alias.
I tried to run a rails app over an Alias and I declared this virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /smart_data /home/pablo/Proyectos/Net-Works/SmartData/smart_data/public
    <Location /smart_data>
        PassengerBaseURI /smart_data
        PassengerAppRoot /home/pablo/Proyectos/Net-Works/SmartData/smart_data
    </Location>
    <Directory /home/pablo/Proyectos/Net-Works/SmartData/smart_data/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works ok, but  my app  read a file from the folder /public/data/ and apache try read this file from /var/www/html/data.

Could someone help me?.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a DocumentRoot within the VirtualHost tags.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Add this line:
  DocumentRoot /home/pablo/Proyectos/Net-Works/SmartData/smart_data/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Since no DocumentRoot is defined there, it's going with the default one (defined somewhere in the same config file, but not nested in any `VirtualHost` tag)

Comment: When I add that line doesn't work, but adding **DocumentRoot /home/pablo/Proyectos/Net-Works/SmartData/smart_data/public** 
then it does, the problem is that everything is running on localhost and not only on localhost/smart_data so when I access to other app like localhost/app2 for example, Rails say no because this route dosen't exists.

Comment: I added 'public' as you pointed out.  Try nesting the DocumentRoot directive inside  either Location or Directory

Comment: Is there another <Location> block for app2?  Does it have its own DocumentRoot directive?

Comment: No, I have a VirtualHost with <Location> only for the rails app, the others apps are on folders with php projects.

Comment: Are the PHP scripts in the default DocumentRoot?  If not, then changing the DocumentRoot shouldn't have impacted them.